# Can't establish a connection retrieve json from a webpage

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I try to retrieve the json from my webpage.

But I can't retrieve the json. It's null. So, I was looking for my error, and see

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //Create the request with a get method
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(ProjectRestDao.url);

            //specify that we want to retrieve a json
            get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            //Run the request //Error here.
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

With the IOException e.

What's the problem?

Comment: please put logcat error.

Comment: Catch the `IOException` and do `e.printMessage();`, then show it to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have the internet permission, which is most probably the issue here.
In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

If not the issue then check the IOException message as previously stated by others.